# How can I separate the String Array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, string

I want to separate the String Arrays in another file or in a String.xml ,but how?

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

**Here is my codes**

---

**MainActivity.class**

```
   package com.skholingua.android.searchview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater.Filter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    String[] stateList;
    String[] anotherStringArray; 
    private SearchView searchView;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stateList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // Sets the default or resting state of the search field.
        // If true, a single search icon is shown by default and
        // expands to show the text field and other buttons when pressed
        //searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        // Sets the hint text to display in the query text field
        //searchView.setQueryHint("State Name");

        int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
        View searchPlateView = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
        if (searchPlateView != null) {
            searchPlateView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String stateName = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
                //String stateName = stateList[position];
                //Log.e("Selected State Name", stateName);

                // Put selected state to intent.
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("selectedState", stateName);
                intent.putExtra("anotherStringArray",anotherStringArray[position]);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    // Called when the query text is changed by the user.

     @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            android.widget.Filter filter = adapter.getFilter();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                filter.filter("");
            } else {
                filter.filter(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">SearchView</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string-array name="stateList">
        <item>Example</item>
        <item>Goa</item>
        <item>Karnataka</item>
        <item>Kerala</item>
        <item>Maharashtra</item>
        <item>Madhya Pradesh</item>
        <item>Tamil Nadu</item>
    </string-array>


     <string-array name="anotherStringArray">
        <item>Example_description</item>
        <item>Goa_description</item>
        <item>Karnataka_description</item>
        <item>Kerala_description</item>
        <item>Maharashtra_description</item>
        <item>Madhya Pradesh_description</item>
        <item>Tamil Nadu_description</item>


    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: do you want to separate them and load them when you start?

Comment: It doesn't seem such an optimization. Rather, I'd say that Android would need more time to recollect all the bits from the different resource files. So, I'd go with a standard single `arrays.xml` - Or even incorporate the arrays in `strings.xml`.

Comment: I update my codes . just watch the codes only . it says unfortunately when I launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in strings.xml as following :

```
<string-array name="stateList">
    <item>Example</item>
    <item>Goa</item>
    <item>Karnataka</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

**Edit:**
Full code for adapter :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stateList));
```

Comment: use getStringArray(R.string.stateList) in your activity

Comment: I update my codes . just watch the codes only . it says unfortunately when I launch

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="my_array">
        <item>Example</item>
        <item>Goa</item>
        <item>Karnataka</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your values folder keep your arrays

[image]

**example :** arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <string-array name="string_array_example">
        <item>"Name"</item>
        <item>"Address"</item>
        <item>"City"</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

This is how you access them back in your class

```
String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_example);
    Log.i("TAG", Arrays.toString(strings));
```

Make sure you use above lines and initialize your arrays before you try to set data !